# Repeated measures for 3+ groups comparing percentages

Tags: spss

I'm new to SPSS. I have data of skin cancer diagnosis for the years 2004 - 2018. I want to compare the changes in distribution of new cases with regards to which body part and compare between the different years. I've managed to create a crosstab and grouped bar graph that shows the percentages but I would like to run a statistical analysis to see if the changes in distribution are significant over time. The groups I have are face, trunk, arm, leg or not specified, the number of cases for each year vary greatly which is why I'm looking to compare the ratios (percentages) between the different body sites. The only explanations I've found all refer to repeated observations of the same subject which is not the case here (a person is only included with their first diagnosis so can only appear in one of the years).

The analysis would be similar to comparing the percentages of an election between 3+ parties and how that distribution changes over the years but I haven't found any such tutorials. Please help!

Comment: Daniel, it seems that you are looking for a statistical analysis. From your description, I would suggest an ANOVA. But I think that [cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) would be the best place for your question. Stack overflow is just for code problems. There is the place for statistic questions. Your odds to get an answer, here or there, will increase if you provide to people a sample of your data in text format (as [Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)), and try to focus on just what you want with it, instead of you accomplished so far.

Answer (score 0):

The CTABLES or Custom Tables procedure, if you have access to it, will let you create a crosstabulation like you mention, and then will let you test both for any changes overall in the distribution of types, as well as comparing each pair of columns for each row.

More generally, problems like this would usually be handled as loglinear or logit models.